# Hiding Vaadin Grid Headers

Tags: grid, vaadin

I am using a `com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid` in my Vaadin 14 sample app. I have added an extra header row and introduced a toggle button for changing its visibility.

Unfortunately, this led me deep down to `com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.ColumnLayer`, which is not visible.

I have also considered dropping the header cell contents and re-adding them. However, this just leaves a full-height row behind. I have also thought about applying some CSS, but could not find a way to, without altering the official source code.

Can anyone help with a more appropriate solution than building my own Grid version (by forking the official implementation)? This feels like pretty common grid functionality to me...

Comment: Have you check this https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-column-toggle

Comment: Yes, but that's about column toggling, not rows (column headers). Unless I am missing something?

Comment: There is no API for header row removal yet: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1538

Comment: We have two tickets, one about removal (what Tatu said) and the other one about hiding in case that's what you are looking for:
https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1218

Comment: Thanks, Serhii! Will hiding as shown in that URL work on the fly? I.e. if setting grid's Id based on a toggle button? I would appreciate an answer, but I will give it a try when I'll return at the office.

Answer (score 0):

To whom might be interested about this...
I have used the dirty workaround mentioned the link shared by Tatu Lund.
However, that only works for `GridSingleSelectionModel`.
For `GridMultiSelectionModel`, the underlying implementation is rather strange.
For example, I complemented the `GridSingleSelectionModel` workaround with setting visibility to false on the Un/Select All checkbox the `GridMultiSelectionModel` generates. This seems to have a listener on it and automatically hides the checkboxes generated by the `GridMultiSelectionModel` on each row. Which is similar to `GridNoneSelectionModel`, so unusable if you need to be able to select items.

Unfortunately, I have trusted that Vaadin 14 should be pretty mature by now, but as I explore it I find myself in the position to rather choose version 8, for instance.
It's not the first issue of this kind and, that being said, I am not sure I understand why is Vaadin releasing new major versions every so often, while they don't seem to be able to deliver a comprehensive, stable and reliable option to their adopters. Vaadin 8 is almost 5 years old, and it looks like no later version is even close to it.